# Retrieve user profiles based on the value of user property with Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, user-profile-service

I need to get all the user profiles that based on a certain user property. Eg "Get all the user that have a property of Department in Finance."

```
$url = "mysite"
$site = Get-SPSite $url
$context = Get-SPServiceContext $site
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($context)
$profiles = $profileManager.GetEnumerator()

while ($profiles.MoveNext()) {
  $userProfile = $profiles.Current
  $name = $userProfile.DisplayName
  $myprop = $UserProfile["Department"]
  Write-Host "$name;$myprop"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer on my question. I will retrieve all users and filter the accordingly. here is the script below.

```
$siteUrl = "http://YOUR_HOSTNAME_HERE"
$outputFile = "c:\temp\sharepoint_user_profiles.csv"


Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$serviceContext = Get-SPServiceContext -Site $siteUrl
$profileManager = New-Object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($serviceContext);
$profiles = $profileManager.GetEnumerator()

$fields = @(
            "SID",
            "ADGuid",
            "AccountName",
            "FirstName",
            "LastName",
            "PreferredName",
            "WorkPhone",
            "Office",
            "Department",
            "Title",
            "Manager",
            "AboutMe",
            "UserName",
            "SPS-Skills",
            "SPS-School",
            "SPS-Dotted-line",
            "SPS-Peers",
            "SPS-Responsibility",
            "SPS-PastProjects",
            "SPS-Interests",
            "SPS-SipAddress",
            "SPS-HireDate",
            "SPS-Location",
            "SPS-TimeZone",
            "SPS-StatusNotes",
            "Assistant",
            "WorkEmail",
            "SPS-ClaimID",
            "SPS-ClaimProviderID",
            "SPS-ClaimProviderType",
            "CellPhone",
            "Fax",
            "HomePhone",
            "PictureURL"
           )

$collection = @()

foreach ($profile in $profiles) {
   $user = "" | select $fields
   foreach ($field in $fields) {
     if($profile[$field].Property.IsMultivalued) {
       $user.$field = $profile[$field] -join "|"
     } else {
       $user.$field = $profile[$field].Value
     }
   }
   $collection += $user
}

$collection | Export-Csv $outputFile -NoTypeInformation
$collection |  Out-GridView
```